# Put a maximum width on a fluid video

Tags: html5-video

I am using this method to make a video fluid

https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

```
.video-container {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
height: 0;
> iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
}
```

When I try to add a maximum width
    maxwidth: 400px;
I am getting a black padding on the top and button of the video, how can avoid this ?

My question is how can I set a maximum width without getting the black padding ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the width to 100% as mentioned in the article, and change the height based on the ratio of the video you've embedded and the width of the window.
This is also in the article (third section)...
*(OR your question was about something else, in this case sorry for misunderstanding)*

Answer (score 0):

Use `auto` for height, then:

(When running code snippet below, select Full page, then resize browser window to see the effect)

```css
video {
  width    : 100%;
  height   : auto;   /* will retain aspect ratio of initial size */
  max-width: 400px;
  }
```

```html
<video muted autoplay="true">
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```